# Sheet specific macro will not run when condition is met

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very simple workbook macro for testing and it is not executing when the condition is met. Do you know why? Macros are enabled and modules are working, however, sheet codes will not work. Any idea why?

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$J$3" Then
        Call macro1
    End If
End Sub
```

And then I tried

```
if A1 = "correct!"
    msgbox "hey"
else <do nothing>
```

If I adjust anything in cell J3 or putting "correct!" in A1 in that sheet, neither code will execute. macro1's code is simply `msgbox "Hey"`. Any idea what I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: Is macro1 in your current workbook? The second code is missing "then" in the first line and replace "else <do nothing>" by "End if" and it should work.

Comment: Please make sure that `Application.EnableEvents` is not set to `False`. You can check for that in the `immediate window`: type `?Application.EnableEvents`

Answer (score 0):

I used `Workbook_SheetChange` and it worked for me:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" And Target.Address = "$J$3" Then
        Call macro1
    End If
End Sub

Sub macro1()
    MsgBox "hello world!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither option had worked. It seems that the code itself will not execute

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your post correctly, you want that once you modify a value in your worksheet at Cell J3, and the value in Cell A1 (at the same worksheet) is "correct!", that a `MsgBox` with "hey" will pop-up.

The code in your `Worksheet_Change` event is good, just modify the code in `macro1` (which can be placed at another code module).

```
Sub macro1()

If Range("A1").Value = "correct!" Then
    MsgBox "hey"
End If

End Sub
```

**Option 2**: using the Like operator

```
If Range("A1").Value Like "correct!" Then
    MsgBox "hey"
End If
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither option had worked. It seems that the code itself will not execute